# How to add a dictionary with a number of keys less than the number of columns of the dataframe to that dataframe into a new line?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a Dataframe like this:

df
[image]

and a dict like this:

result={'a':'cat,'b':'kiss'}

Can someone please help me to create a simple dataframe like below image? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#) with the [*DataFrame*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor :

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(result, index=[len(df)+1])])
```

Alternatively, use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) :

```
df.loc[len(df)+1, list(result.keys())] = list(result.values())
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

      a     b      c
1  food  hate   rain
2   dog  like  storm
3  same  love  flood
4   cat  kiss    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use same this append() method

1. Let's say df1 = df
2. Converting dictionary to dataframe using
   pd.Dataframe(result), let's say df2
3. Appending df2 to the df1 using append()

A continuous index value will be maintained

```
df1.append(df2, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: append function will be removed soon in future pandas version